# Better syntax for adding a column from other data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two indexed data tables, and I want to add a column from one table to the other by index. My current approach is as follows:

```
A <- data.table(index = seq(6,10), a = rnorm(5))
B <- data.table(index = seq(10), b = rnorm(10))
setkey(B, index)
A[, b := B[.(A[,index]), b]]
```

While this gets the job done, the syntax seems a bit redundant. Is there a cleaner way to perform the same operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with a join

```
A[B, b := b, on = .(index)]
```

The `setkey` step is not needed here

Comment: Thanks. How about if the `index` columns don't have the same name? For instance, assume `B` has index column `index1` instead.

Comment: @user3294195  In that case change the `on` to `on = .(index = index1)]` i.e. `A[B, b := b, on = .(index = index1)]`